# Open FDA API - LIKE search condition

Tags: openfda

I am interested in finding a syntax for the LIKE search condition.

The query syntax example is
https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=brand_name:aspirin

I have to enter the whole word (aspirin) for getting result.
Is there any way to get result with the part of the word (for example "asp"), using symbols like % or %s for LIKE search?

Getting no result with this query
https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=brand_name:aspiri%

Answer (score 1):

I'm Jack with the openFDA team. At the moment there is no LIKE search condition enabled for openFDA. We will discuss it internally and consider the implementation of this feature. For more details on the available search features, please check [the documentation](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/).

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your answers today. Please consider setting an alert on [tag:openfda], or coming back more often. Users from your site are directed to this site, which is fine as long as someone is here to answer.

Comment: Also, still many to answer! https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openfda